# Onmouseover - need to set position of new image

Tags: javascript, css

This is driving me crazy. Here is the code I am using - with my website names as xxxxx due to sensitive nature of site. I need to set a position for the image that comes up when you hover over. Something like this - position:absolute; TOP:200px; LEFT:340px; WIDTH:500px; HEIGHT:200px.  The image I am hovering over should remain static.

```
<head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
loadImage1 = new Image();
loadImage1.src = "http:xxxx/LgThumbxxx.png";
staticImage1 = new Image();
staticImage1.src = "http:xxx/smThumbxxx.png";

loadImage2 = new Image();
loadImage2.src = "http:xxxx/LgThumbxxxxx.png";
staticImage2 = new Image();
staticImage2.src = "http:xxx/smThumb_xxxxxx.png";

loadImage3 = new Image();
loadImage3.src = "http:xx/LgThumb_xxx.png";
staticImage3 = new Image();
staticImage3.src = "http:xxxx/smThumb_xxxx.png";

// End -->
</script>
</head>

<body>


<span onmouseover="image1.src=loadImage1.src;" onmouseout="image1.src=staticImage1.src;">
<img name="image1" src="http:xxx/Thumbxxx.png" border=0></span>

<span onmouseover="image2.src=loadImage2.src;" onmouseout="image2.src=staticImage2.src;">
<img name="image2" src="http:xxxxx/Thumbxxxx.png" border=0></span>

<span onmouseover="image3.src=loadImage3.src;" onmouseout="image3.src=staticImage3.src;">
<img name="image3" src="http://xxxx/Thumb_xxxxx.png" border=0></span>


</body>
```

Comment: JSfiddle please and clarification of what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: a static picture with a mouseover to a different image. Want the new image or larger image to move out to the left of what I am hovering over.

Comment: The code is working perfectly except the position of the image displayed upon hover.

Comment: JSfiddle please...You can use placeholder images if necessary.

Comment: I do not believe you understand what I need. Is there a way to attach a screenshot in this forum? I can explain it better that way.